# Creating an end screen for my game using javascript, css, and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to create an end screen for my candy crush game utilizing a timer but for some reason when the timer hits 0 and the conditions are met, the screen doesn't come up. Any idea why this might be happening?

```js
function timer() {
  var seconds = 120;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("safeTimerDisplay").innerHTML = seconds;
    seconds--;
    if (seconds < 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

timer();


function endGame() {
  if (seconds === 0 && score > 1800) {
    console.log(endWindow1)
  }
}
```

```css
#EndWindow1 {
  background: url("./endscreen.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="EndWindow1" style="display:none;"></div>
<h1>Timer: <span id="safeTimerDisplay"></span></h1>
```

I tried using a conditional and stating that if the user's score was over 1800 and the clock hits 0, a specific image should come up that I specified using the file in the css folder. When the clock hits 0 though, nothing ends up happening and you can proceed with the game as normal.

Comment: Where do you call your `endGame` function? The `seconds` variable is currently within the timer function scope, therefore, the `endGame` function is not able to access it when running.

Comment: What do you expect `console.log(endWindow1)` to do?

Comment: @Joushua While this is true, the `endGame()` does not need to access the block-scope variable `seconds`. You should call the function from within that block in the first place. However the code contains far more issues then that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. Your element `EndWindow1` only has a background image but no content and a default height of `auto`. As the element is empty the height will be 0 and as such always invisible.
2. You never call the function `endGame()`.
3. `console.log()` does what the name suggests, it adds a console log entry for debugging purposes. It does not hide/show elements.
4. You never referenced your element `EndWindow1`but rather called a non-declared variable/constant.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const TIMER = document.getElementById('safeTimerDisplay');
  const END_WINDOW = document.getElementById('EndWindow1');
  let remaining_time = 10;
  let score = 1801;
  
  function timer() {
    let timer = setInterval(function() {
      TIMER.textContent = remaining_time;
      remaining_time--;
      switch (remaining_time) {
        case 0:
          endGame();
          break;
        case -1:
          clearInterval(timer);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  timer();

  function endGame() {
    END_WINDOW.classList.toggle('d-none', !(score > 1800));
  }
})
```

```css
#EndWindow1 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="EndWindow1" class="d-none"></div>
<h1>Timer: <span id="safeTimerDisplay"></span></h1>
```

##### Code Refining:

instead of using:

```js
if (seconds === 0 && score > 1800) {
  console.log(endWindow1)
}
```

and checking for 2 conditions you can add to your timer `setInterval` the call for `endGame` within your if condition. You already check there the time continuously.

You do not need an `if` condition. YOu should hide/show elements by adding/removing CSS classes. As such you can use `classList.toggle` to show/hide depending on a condition.